# Bitcoin not being recieved even after high transaction fee

Tags: transaction-fees

https://gyazo.com/61b5ca1bc5a007ba55ffdd37fc8c0db6
Keep sending bitcoins to multiple addresses with bitcoin core but its not getting confirmed... some have been sent months ago. I used a transaction fee of .00007089/kb whats going on?

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you could provide a link to some of the addresses so that we can see for ourselves whether there is anything amiss. Otherwise, the referenced fee would be low but should have gotten included in the past weeks at some points.